# Manually starting 3G connection in Android, and keeping it on

Tags: android, linux, networking, android-networking

How do you start the 3G data connection in Android at the same time WiFi is on? I tried

```
IConnectivityManager.setMobileDataEnabled(enabled); // via reflection
```

and it works in the emulator, but in my real phone (Droid 2), it briefly turns on then back off again.

From the shell (adb shell), `ip link` provides the details of the 3G connection:

`15: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 3 link/ppp`

However, it is only available when WiFi is off. When WiFi is on and I try to turn it on manually, it complains the ppp0 device doesn't exist.

```
bash-3.2# ip link set ppp0 up
ip link set ppp0 up
Cannot find device "ppp0"
```

When I try to list the device, I can't even find it

```
bash-3.2# ls /dev/ppp*
ls /dev/ppp*
/dev/ppp
```

Comment: I have a feeling I will have to cross-compile a C program to natively turn on the radio. I just can't get an instance of a Java ConnectivityService object to try various other app-level method calls.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it's not possible to get 3g and WiFi simultaneously connected without modifying Android platform source code (at least versions 2.3 and 4). The main problem is hardcoded priorities of connections defined in [frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread-release/core/res/res/values/config.xml):

```
<!-- This string array should be overridden by the device to present a list of network
attributes. This is used by the connectivity manager to decide which networks can coexist
based on the hardware -->
    <!-- An Array of "[Connection name],[ConnectivityManager connection type],
[associated radio-type],[priority] -->
 <!--                   ^^^^^^^^^^---------- Connection priority -->

    <string-array translatable="false" name="networkAttributes">
        <item>"wifi,1,1,1"</item>
        <item>"mobile,0,0,0"</item>
        <item>"mobile_mms,2,0,2"</item>
        <item>"mobile_supl,3,0,2"</item>
        <item>"mobile_hipri,5,0,3"</item>
    </string-array>
```

This config.xml is then read by [ConnectivityService](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread-release/services/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java) which is subscribed to connect/disconnect events. And in connect handler it decides what it should do with other connections:

```
private void handleConnect(NetworkInfo info) {

        //------------8-<--------------------------

        // if this is a default net and other default is running
        // kill the one not preferred
        if (mNetAttributes[type].isDefault()) {
            if (mActiveDefaultNetwork != -1 && mActiveDefaultNetwork != type) {
                if ((type != mNetworkPreference &&
                        mNetAttributes[mActiveDefaultNetwork].mPriority >
                        //                                    ^^^^^^^^^ --- From config.xml
                        mNetAttributes[type].mPriority) ||
                        //                   ^^^^^^^^^-------- From config.xml
                        mNetworkPreference == mActiveDefaultNetwork) {
                        // don't accept this one
                        if (DBG) Slog.v(TAG, "Not broadcasting CONNECT_ACTION " +
                                "to torn down network " + info.getTypeName());
                        teardown(thisNet);
                        return;
          //------------8-<--------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping both active at the same time by modifying your connectivityservice,
but I'd advice against it, since it'll most likely destroy your battery life.

See [here](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/) if you want to give it a try anyway (and make sure you have a backup, obviously)

Comment: Thanks, saw that, but it has to be deployable and work for (most) everyone's phone.

Comment: Problem is that this is standard in Android (certain phones can have both active at the same time, but most phones don't). So you'd have to find a way to overide the android code in your app (of which I'm not sure wether or not it's possible)

Comment: I know it's possible because I've seen tether apps do it. I only need to turn them both on to have a multi-ip interface host, but without the bridge.

Comment: Tether apps work differently: when you have both your data and your wifi active, they both request internet and your phone will give priority to wifi. When you are tethering, only your data is requesting internet and your wifi is 'sending' (for lack of a better word) the internet (thus not requesting it)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a specific machine you can try [ConnectivityManager.requestRouteToHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Naa I tried that. It doesn't turn the radio on and assign an IP. I need access to any host, not just a specific one anyways.